# Why is the camera opposite to the general object quaternion

Tags: javascript, three.js

why is the camera on position(0, 0, -1) and lookAt(0, 0, 1) quaternion is(_x: -3.141592653589793, _y: 0, _z: -3.141592653589793)?
This result is the opposite of the general object

I try to create a group and assign its position(0, 0, -1) and lookAt(0, 0, 1) quaternion is (_x: -0, _y: 0, _z: -0), these two are both objects, why are the results different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Object3D "looks down" its own **positive** z-axis. You can see this described [in the docs for `Object3D.getWorldDirection()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=bject#api/en/core/Object3D.getWorldDirection) method.

However, a Camera "looks down" its own **negative** z-axis, as described in [the docs for `Camera.getWorldDirection()`](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=camera#api/en/cameras/Camera.getWorldDirection).

This means that an Object3D placed at `0, 0, 0` doesn't need to rotate to look at `0, 0, 1`, but a camera needs to rotate 180º around the y-axis to look at the same spot.

Comment: It turns out that the two objects are not the same.
Thank you for your answer.